# unknown error:<class keyerror>( the cache has no package named linux-image-5.19.0 43-generic:amd64)

Tags: dependencies

I got an error message saying
**unknown error:'<class 'keyError'>'(the cache has no package named linux-image-5.19.0-43-generic:amd64)'usually means that your installed package has unmet dependencies.**

I have been using my system with OS 22.04 for the last two months and this error message appeared today.
Any solution?